How does this proof that for every infinite set $A$ there exists an injection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ rely on the axiom of choice?
I'm currently taking a course in proof-writing, and the following question came up on a problem set:
Prove that for every infinite set $A$, there is a one-to-one function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$.
I've written a proof that (I think) is correct, but I've also been doing some reading and it seems that this statement relies on the axiom of (countable) choice, but I'm not sure why this is the case. Here is my proof for reference:
Choose some $a_0 \in A$. We define $f(0) := a_0$. Now suppose we have some natural number $n > 0$, and $f$ is defined for all $0 \leq k < n$. Then let
$$S_n := \bigcup_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\\{f(k)\\},\text{ } T_n := A \setminus S_n.$$
Choose some element $a_n \in T_n$, and define $f(n) := a_n$. By induction we have that $f$ is defined for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It suffices to show that $f$ is injective.
Suppose we have $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i \not= j$. Without loss of generality we assume $i < j$. Clearly $f(j) \in T_j$. We also have that $f(i) \in S_j$, since $i < j$. Then $f(i) \not\in T_j$, thus $f(i) \not= f(j)$.
My understanding of CC is that it allows us to state that there exists a choice function for any countable family of non-empty sets, but it doesn't seem to make any claim as to whether a particular countable family has a choice function. It feels like in this case since we aren't choosing each element "at the same time", we ought to be able to appeal to the principle of induction to recursively define $f$ without evoking CC, but this isn't the case. Assuming my proof is correct (it may not be), which step relies on CC? Am I missing something else?

Is this also the case for "Choose some $a_0 \in A$", or is there something special about "choosing" within an inductive step?

@Numeral: That is absolutely false.

@AsafKaragila Apologies. Would you care to elaborate?

@Numeral: To choose an element from a non-empty set you do not need the axiom of choice, just the logical inference rule known as Existential Instantiation.

@AsafKaragila If I understand correctly $\exists x\in A \implies a_0\in A$ for a new constant symbol $a_0$. My logic is quite rusty, but how do we find a corresponding element of A? Would the interpretation of this symbol require choice?

@Numeral: You don't find. If you say "Let $x$ be a real number", you're not "searching for it" or "constructing it". You're simply naming it, and it appears. This is one of the beautiful things in modern mathematics. This is how EI works, since $A$ is non-empty, we can conjure one of its elements into the proof.

Your proof, as written, uses a slightly stronger principle, Dependent Choice. The reason is that the choice of $f(k)$ depends on the previous choices. If, for example, you chose that $f(0)=a$, then $f(1)$ cannot be $a$.
The point is that at the end you are not choosing one or two, or $4{,}193$ many elements. You are choosing infinitely many of them.
But in any case, your proof is not using $\sf CC$ "per se". Which is why you seem to be confused as to what is the family from which you're choosing.
To use $\sf CC$ in order to prove the claim, we need to have a slightly more elaborate proof.

Let $A_n$ be the set of all injective functions $n\to A$. Since $A$ is infinite, $A_n$ is non-empty for all $n$.
Let $F$ be a choice function from $\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, here we use $\sf CC$. Then consider the function given by concatenating the functions given by $F$. Namely, $f\colon\Bbb N\to A$ is given by $f(n)=F(k)(i)$ where $i+\sum_{j<k}j=n$ with $i<k+1$.
Finally, refine $f$ by recursion to be injective. Since $F(k)$ has length $k$, we are guaranteed that by $F(2^k+1)$ we will have found a new element that did not exist in any $F(j)$ for $j<k$. So indeed, this refinement works through all of $\Bbb N$.

